# ¿Cómo puedo pasar como parametro un Enum que implementa una interfaz?

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo 3 clases enumeradas que pueden ser el valor de un atributo en una clase sellada.
La propiedad se definió de tipo `Enum<*>`

Cada clase enumerada cuenta con un `String` y un `Int`, lucen algo así

```
enum class Enum1(private val type: String, private val _color: Int) : GetColor {
    VALUE1("type1", R.color.color1)
    VALUE2("type2", R.color.color2)

    override val color: Int
        get() = _color
}
```

las cuales implementan la interfaz `GetColor`

La interfaz GetColor unicamente tiene una propiedad abstracta, que representa un color

```
interface GetColor {
    val color: Int
}
```

Y como se ve en el código de ejemplo, cada clase Enum se encarga de sobreescribir la variable con su valor de `_color`

Por lo que en la clase sellada tengo que cambiar el tipo de parametro, para que identifique que implementa la interface `GetColor`

En Java sería algo así

```
public ConstructorClass(Enum<? extends GetColor> enum)
```

Sin embargo en Kotlin entiendo que se usa la palabra reservada `out` para indicar cualquier subtipo de una clase/Interfaz

Por lo que el constructor de mi clase sellada luce así

```
sealed class Card (
    @SerializedName("id") open val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name") open val name: String,
    @SerializedName("type") open val type: Enum<out GetColor>,
    @SerializedName("desc") open val description: String,
    @SerializedName("race") open val race: Enum<*>,
    @SerializedName("archetype") open val archetype: String?,
    @SerializedName("card_images") open val card_images: List<Image>
)
```

Y obtengo este error por parte del IDE
**`Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Enum<out GetColor>`'**

¿Cómo puedo indicar el tipo de dato para este parametro?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu `Enum1` debería ser una sealed class y `Card` una data class, necesitaría un poco mas de contexto para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: La clase `Card` es sealed porque sus clases hijas se conocen en tiempo de compilación.
Sus clases hijas son data, como por ejemplo la clase MonsterCard

`data class MonsterCard(/*paramethers*/)) : Card(/*paramethers*/)`